# PHP multi param function

Tags: php, function

I need a practical approach to pass multiple parameters to a function which is used globally over several scripts to dump a table from a database.

It accepts multiple parameters (with default values for each) and it depends on whether the scripts needs a specific option to be activated inside the function.

For example:

```
function dump_table($sumtotal=false, $countrows=false, $yadalada=false... etc){
```

The question is, if I have 10 different parameters and a script needs only parameter 10 to be true I must call something like this:

```
dump_table(false,false,false,false...., true)
```

So... Is there another way to make it easily scalable without the overhead in the function calls?

I though to use objects, but afaik It would involve a class and instance creation on every call.

Is there a way to make something like this in php (javascript-like style):

```
dump_table({opt1: true, opt10: true, opt99: true})
```

Or even

```
$options = { count: true, sumtotals: true };
dump_table($options);
```

- Inside the function I would use something like `property_exists` to check which ones to set...

thx

Comment: _if I have 10 different parameters_ This would be the wrong approach. Your code design would then be messy. Think about single responsibility...

Comment: A simple associative array ...?

Comment: I would probably create a class that handles that instead of a function. Then you can have the settings as properties with default values and setters and getters for the params.

Comment: @CBroe: indeed.... `function dump_table($p=array()){
  print_r($p);
 }`. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Why the downvote ??? It s a real problem and the answer below is very inonovative, informative and should help a lot of others in the community..... =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such approach:

```
function yourFunction(array $parameters = array()) {
   //here you should define all possible parameters with their defaults
   $param_1 = true;
   $param_2 = false;
   ...
   $param_10 = true;
   ...
   $param_N = 'whatever';

   //and now simply extract passed parameters
   extract($parameters, EXTR_OVERWRITE | EXTR_IF_EXISTS);
}
```

Usage:

```
yourFunction(['param_1' => false, 'param_10' => 'something']);
```

`extract($parameters, EXTR_OVERWRITE | EXTR_IF_EXISTS)` will overwrite default defined variables with those that would be passed through `$parameters` array.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe suggested, an associative array could be the solution you are looking for:

```
$options = array(
    'count' => true,
    'sumtotals' => true,
    'option3' => false,
    ...
    'option9' => false
    );
dump_table($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take some default options array and 1 array as input to override:

```
<?php

function foo($optionsgiven = array())
{
   $defaultoptions = ['width' => 10, 'height' => 20, 'weight' => 30];

   foreach($defaultoption as $key => $value) {
     if(isset($optionsgiven[$key])) {
        $options[$key] = $optionsgiven[$key];
     }
     else {
        $options[$key] = $value;
     }

   }
}

// main script
$x = foo(['width' => 100]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely the wrong way of doing it.
I'd recommend using json_encode() and json_decode() to encode and decode the arrays.
You can set all the properties to an array.

```
$array = array(
    "sumtotal" = false,
    "countrows" =false,
    "yadalada" = false
);
dump_table(json_encode($array));
```

Inside the function you have to decode that array `json_decode($array, true);` and you can then build your if else statments